# What is the null hypothesis in the Mann-Whitney test?

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

Let $X_1$ be a random value from distribution 1 and let $X_2$ be a random value from distribution 2. I thought that the null hypothesis for the Mann-Whitney test was $P(X_1 < X_2) = P(X_2 < X_1)$.

If I run simulations of the Mann-Whitney test on data from normal distributions with equal means and equal variances, with $\alpha=0.05$, I get Type I error rates which are very close to 0.05. However, if I make the variances unequal (but leave the means equal), the proportion of simulations in which the null hypothesis is rejected becomes larger than 0.05, which I didn't expect, since $P(X_1 < X_2) = P(X_2 < X_1)$ still holds. This happens when I use `wilcox.test` in R, regardless of whether I have `exact=TRUE`, `exact=FALSE, correct=TRUE`, or `exact=FALSE, correct=FALSE`.

Is the null hypothesis something different from what I've written above, or is it just that the test is inaccurate in terms of Type I error if the variances are unequal?

Comment: See also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56649/mann-whitney-null-hypothesis-under-unequal-variance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Hollander & Wolfe](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471190454) pp 106-7,

> Let $F$ be the distribution function corresponding to population 1 and
>   $G$ be the distribution function corresponding to population 2.  The
>   null hypothesis is:  $H_O: F(t)=G(t)$ for every $t$.  The null
>   hypothesis asserts that the $X$ variable and the $Y$ variable have the
>   same probability distribution, but the common distribution is not
>   specified.

Strictly speaking this describes the Wilcoxon test, but $U=W-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, so they're equivalent.